# Default session timeout for Apache Tomcat applications

Tags: java, tomcat, session-timeout

What is the default session timeout for web applications deployed on Tomcat5.5? Is it browser specific? In my web application, default timeout is mentioned neither in `web.xml` nor in code.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

## Define inside web.xml

Open `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` and find this:

```xml
<!-- ==================== Default Session Configuration ================= -->
<!-- You can set the default session timeout (in minutes) for all newly   -->
<!-- created sessions by modifying the value below.                       -->

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

All webapps implicitly inherit from this default web descriptor. You can override these default settings via your webapp's own `web.xml` file.

This is actually from my Tomcat 7 (Windows) but I think Tomcat 5.5's configuration is not very different