# How to Auto close java application session after Power OFF and after net connection disconnected

Tags: java, jsp

How can I automatically close java application session after Power OFF and after net connection disconnected.

Comment: Please  give us more details.  What do you mean by "Power OFF" ?  Do you mean when the client loses power on  his or hers computer?  Who is losing their connection?

Comment: Yes correct these two situation will be there. Frist is Client loses power on his computer. Second is losing their network connection. Wants solution on both situation.

Comment: Do you know about  session-timeout ?  If not, then see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433070/default-session-timeout-for-apache-tomcat-applications   and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382895/session-timeout-in-web-xml     You can use that to  terminate  the session after  the InactiveInterval that you specify.   If that doesn't meet your requirements, then  we could   talk about other  more complicated  ways.  But, they could never distinguish  between  a loss of power and  the  client simply closing his browser.